# Dockerfile: how to configure redis properly

Tags: docker, redis, dockerfile

my dockerfile

```
FROM redislabs/rejson:latest
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
VOLUME ["/data"]

CMD ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
EXPOSE 6379
```

in my `redis.conf` i have set `bind 0.0.0.0` and `requirepass foobared`

i build the docker file and run it and it says its ready to accept connections

terminal > `redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379 -a foobared`

and it will just hang, it wont even connect.

I'm pretty sure it has to deal with the ports, but can't figure it out.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What are container logs showing? `docker logs -f container_name`

Comment: i did not run it detached @AlexeyR., i can see the logs on my other terminal. it seems like its not even making connections in the first place. nothing is logged.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose):

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them to high-order ports.

So you need to publish your ports explicitly when run image. For example:

`docker run -p 6379:6379 redislabs/rejson`